# Finishing Concrete basement floors

Tags: concrete, basement, floor, sealing

Alright! This is a 4 part question! I live in a new build in Ottawa Ontario and would like to finish my basement. Basement is below grade, and the house has been up for 6 months.

1 )I'm planning on using [DMX](https://www.homedepot.ca/product/dmx-plastics-limited-dmx-1-step-20/1001513953?eid=PS_GOOGLE_D23%20-%20CM_E-Comm_GGL_Shopping_PLA_EN_Flooring_Flooring_PLA_EN__PRODUCT_GROUP_aud-763183629249:pla-341957376360&gclid=Cj0KCQjwl4v4BRDaARIsAFjATPm8aw0PkpqoQz7qlzoAmc1H_WRvhmPi1kQtrPv0EirADeLj-bFv64QaApCzEALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds) under my subfloor. Should I still etch and seal my concrete floors?

2. If I do seal the floors, what type of sealant should I use? Any advice?
3. Do I turn off my furnace while I complete the work? Should I tape around it? Something about acid being near my furnace......
4. How much will this stink and for how long? I have an 8 month old and don't want him breathing in the stuff!

Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your concrete hasn't been sealed, you need to seal it. Some of the best sealers around are the waterbased epoxy sealers. They are low fumes and non flammable. For best results, the concrete should be etched. Check with your builder because they might have already done all this.

The furnace should be protected if acid etching but can remain on when sealing if using non flammable products

As far as how long it will stink, you really need to check the individual product you'd be using.

After reading about DMX, there's no reason to believe it wouldn't work with water based epoxy sealers but checking with the vendors would hurt. They are constantly changing their information on what you can and can't do.

Comment: Thank you! How would you suggest protecting the furnace? Anything specific?

Comment: @Flujee I would just wrap it with some visqueen. Can you raise the furnace to seal under it?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I look into the visqueen! Thank you for your time! I appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

1. I know nothing about that product so i do  not know if it is necessary to have the concrete sealed when using the product. Have you read the installation instruction regarding installation on concrete ?
2. Concrete sealer. (there are many)
3. Depends on the type of sealer you are using, read the instruction concerning flammability.
4. Depends on the type of sealer you are using, read the instruction concerning safety precautions and ventilation.

If you have a more specific question then please update.